# How do I insert the contents of a subselect in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to do something like

```
insert into my table (select * from anothertable where id < 5)
```

What is the correct MSSQL syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM AnotherTable
WHERE AnotherTable.ID < 5
```

Comment: Great.

As others have mentioned, you want to be sure that the columns you're selecting from AnotherTable match the columns in MyTable.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax looks correct, but you the fields have to match exactly otherwise it won't work.

You can specify the fields eg:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(COL1, COL2, COL3) 
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM anotherTable where anotherTable.id < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`Insert Into MyTable
   (
          Col1,
          Col2,
       Col3
   )
Select
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
From
    AnotherTable
Where
    ID < 5`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
select *
into MyTable
from AnotherTable
where ID < 5
```

which will create MyTable with the required columns, as well as fill the data in.